# How to use pthread right in my project? I need thread in thread. (with opencv)

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, pthreads, wrapper

> My env. is Win 10, VS 2017.

I've written c++ project which has high complexity because of necessary, and I'm testing on own built library using multi-thread processing in main function.

When I used c++ thread in code, everything was fine. Every result was correct and same each other.
I had to change thread using pthread, but I failed to get the same result with using c++ thread.

I use identical video file as input through whole 4 thread, but the results from each 4 thread are not same.
I think some logic is missing for sync, or there are some interruption between one and other capture thread.
Could you please help me to figure out what is going wrong?

Or would you mind to recommend me other strong structure for my project? I'm not good at architecture..
[briefly draw my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKqv.png)
Thanks.

Test.cpp

```
#include "A_dll.hpp"
#pragma comment(lib, "A_dll.lib")

void* thread_main(void* p)
{
    Arg* arg = *(Arg *)p;

    std::vector<pAWarper> vecPA;
    while(1){
        1. opencv capture video
        for( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            2. **vecPA[i] = A_Create(i);**
            3. **A_SetArgs(vecPA[i], x,y,z);**
            4. **A_Run(vecPA[i]);**
            5. **A_Stop(vecPA[i]);**
            6. **A_GetResultImg(vecPA[i]);**
            7. opencv display (imshow)
        }
    }       
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++){
        **A_Destroy(vecPA[i]);**
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int THD_NUM_MAX = 4;

    vector<pthread_t> vecThds(THD_NUM_MAX);
    vector<Args> arg(THD_NUM_MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < THD_NUM_MAX; i++)
    {
        arg[i] = { i, OB_NUM_MAX };
        if (pthread_create(&vecThds[i], NULL, thread_main, (void *)&arg[i]) < 0)
        {
            perror("error:");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    int status;
    for (int i = 0; i < THD_NUM_MAX; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(vecThds[i], (void **)&status);
    }   
}
```

A_dll.hpp & A_dll.cpp --> warp class and export as dll

```
#include "classA.h"

typedef void* pAWarper;
__DLLTYPE pAWarper A_Create(int id)
{
    classA* ptrA = new classA(id);
    return (classA)ptrA;
}

__DLLTYPE void A_SetArgs(pAWarper p, x, y, z)
{
    classA* ptrA = new classA(id);
    ptrA->set(x,y,z);
}

__DLLTYPE void A_Run(pAWarper p)
{
    classA* ptrA = new classA(id);
    ptrA->start();
}

__DLLTYPE void A_Stop(pAWarper p)
{
    classA* ptrA = new classA(id);
    ptrA->stop();
}

__DLLTYPE void A_GetResultImg(pAWarper p, cv::Mat & res)
{
    classA* ptrA = new classA(id);
    ptrA->getRes(res);
}
```

A.h & A.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include "cThread.hpp"
class classA : cThread{
    void set( x,y,z);

    std::unique_ptr<classB> pB;
    virtual void run(){
        pB->do_something();
    }
}
```

B.h

```
class classB{
    do_something();
}
```

cThread.h

```
#include <pthread.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVC2.lib")

class cThread {
protected:
    pthread_t mThread;
    bool threadRunFlag;
public:
    cThread();
    virtual ~cThread();
    virtual void run() = 0;
    static void* run_(void*);
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    bool IsRun();
};

cThread.cpp

#include "cThread.h"

cThread::cThread()
{
    this->threadRunFlag = false;
};

cThread::~cThread()
{
    if (this->IsRun())
        this->Stop();
};

bool cThread::IsRun()
{
    return this->threadRunFlag;
}

void* cThread::run_(void* aThis)
{
    cThread* pThis = (cThread*)aThis;
    if (pThis->IsRun())
    {
        pThis->run();
    }
    return 0;
};

void cThread::Start()
{
    this->threadRunFlag = true;
    pthread_create(&mThread, NULL, &cThread::run_, (void*)this);
}

void cThread::Stop()
{
    this->threadRunFlag = false;
    pthread_join(mThread, NULL);
};
```

Comment: *" I had to change thread using pthread"* Why?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to use library filed and project both linux and windows. So I'm testing several thread method.

Comment: @AnniYu C++ threads, i.e. `std::thread`, are supported on every platform.

Comment: @walnut I used std::thread first, but when I was searching about linux(I have no knowledge) there are many examples using pthread. So I thought for a sec that linux's thread is pthread as default. If it is safe both linux and win, I'll use std::thread. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AnniYu pthread is just a possible backend implementation for std::thread. Many examples can be easily translated from pthread usage to std::thread using Google and various other ressources.